# Time localized wrongly in Python

Tags: python, python-2.7, datetime, localization

Using python Im trying to localize a datetime value to timezone "America/Chicago" which is -06:00 currently.
I get the timezone the following way:

```
>>> import pytz
>>> tz = pytz.timezone("America/Chicago")
<DstTzInfo 'America/Chicago' CST-1 day, 18:00:00 STD>
```

when I localize a date:

```
>>> my_date = tz.localize(datetime.now())
datetime.datetime(2016, 9, 24, 17, 4, 43, 439824, tzinfo=<DstTzInfo 'America/Chicago' CDT-1 day, 19:00:00 DST>)
```

Notice it is the wrong timezone after localize:

```
<DstTzInfo 'America/Chicago' CDT-1 day, 19:00:00 DST>
```

And later when i ask for the offset, you can see it is confirmed it has the wrong offset:

```
>>> my_date.strftime("%z")
'-0500'
```

Exactly the same happend if I use astimezone instead:

```
>>>my_date
datetime.datetime(2016, 9, 24, 22, 15, 1, 620364, tzinfo=<UTC>)

>>>my_date.astimezone(tz)
datetime.datetime(2016, 9, 24, 17, 15, 1, 620364, tzinfo=<DstTzInfo 'America/Chicago' CDT-1 day, 19:00:00 DST>)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Btw Chicago is observing DST now. So -05.00 is the right offset. Pytz timezone by default has the standard time, but when localized can account for day light saving based on the date(as in your case).